# Какого типа `1.`?

Tags: c++, c, типы-данных, language-lawyer, ideone

В такой программе на Си

```
double x = 1;
x %= 1.;
```

получаю сообщение об ошибке http://ideone.com/dDurEH

> invalid operands to binary % (have 'double' and **'long double'**)

из которого следует, что выражение `1.` имеет тип `long double`.

Тот же код, но на плюсах показывает просто `double` http://ideone.com/nd49YK:

> invalid operands of types 'double' and **'double'** to binary 'operator%'

Да и такая проверка на плюсах тоже за double http://ideone.com/HCw0GG:

```
auto x = 1.;

cout 
<< sizeof (double) << ' '      // 8
<< sizeof (long double) << ' ' // 12
<< sizeof x << ' '             // 8
<< sizeof 1. << endl;          // 8
```

Получается, С++ выводит тип `double`, а не `long double`.

**Итак, это одни из различий Си и Си++ или же косяк компилятора?**
**Какой правильный тип у константы `1.` и зависит ли он от языка?**

Comment: Я на arduino объявляю double всегда с точкой. Думаю, стоит попробовать double x = 1.;

Comment: @ilyaplot, а как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: В плюсах `1.` - точно `double`. В сях - надо порыть стандарт. Видимо компилятор [шалит](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Rp9aAtxGAoqRPmvC).

Comment: @alexolut, так я потому и полез плюсы проверять, что помню, что double.

Comment: В "Полном справочнике по С" (C in a Nutshell) четко сказано, что без суффиксов - просто `double`. Чтоб был `long double`, нужен суффикс - `1.L`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Константа вида `1.` имеет тип `double` как в C++, так и в C.

- C

  > 6.4.4.2/4: An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. If suffixed by the letter for `F`, it has type `float`. If suffixed by the letter `l` or `L`, it has type `long double`.
- C++

  > 2.14.4/1: The type of a floating literal is `double` unless explicitly specified by a suffix.

Компилятор, используемый на ideone.com [имеет версию](http://ideone.com/eFqfp1) `5.1.1 20150711`. Так что может иметь смысл погонять её локально, если у кого есть возможность.
Похожий компилятор на goodbolt (5.1) [выдает ошибку с правильными типами](https://godbolt.org/g/wwLmZY):

> ```
> error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'
> error: in evaluation of 'operator%=(double, double)'
> ```

Возможная причина кроется в значении [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#IEEE.C2.A0754_floating_point_support), которое задает точность вычислений для внутренних операций. Для ideone это значение равно `2`, т.к. [используется 32-битный компилятор](http://ideone.com/dcIyAE):

> For gcc, `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2` is the default on 32 bit x86

Т.е. все вычисления с плавающей точкой опираются на тип `long double`.

Хотя, по правде говоря, это и не должно влиять на тип вещественной константы.

Как оказалось, изменить значение `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` с `0` на `2` на 64 bit компиляторе g++ можно путём добавления ключа `-mfpmath=387`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main()
{
    // 1 % 1.;
    printf( "%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
}
```

[Результат:](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FlKrTLlYbDc8wvo7)

> ```
> 2
> ```

В этом случае сообщение об ошибке [для второго аргумента также выводит тип `long double`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9InBQc8tHvB433Mg) как и исходное на ideone (для 32 bit):

> ```
> invalid operands to binary % (have 'int' and 'long double')
> ```

Для clang нужен другой ключ: [`-mno-sse`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uNPxV67wQtwys17B). При этом диагностическое сообщение уже для обоих типов [выводит `double`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9InBQc8tHvB433Mg):

> ```
> invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')
> ```

При этом первый, как мне кажется, должен всё же был остаться `int`.

Подводя итог, можно сказать, что оба компилятора в диагностических сообщениях имеют проблемы с выводом исходного типа операндов.

Comment: Им пора обновлять компилятор - одни баги...

Comment: gcc 5.2.1 20151010 тоже правильные типы выдает

Comment: @Qwertiy возможно, компилятором ограничиться не получится. См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: Но `sizeof` показал 8, т. е. если программа компилируется, то никакого `long double` нет. Как ещё можно проверить?

Comment: @Qwertiy `double` и `long double` вполне могут быть одинакового размера. Но это не значит, что типы одинаковые.

Comment: Там long double 12. Я же это тоже вывел. Там `8 12 8`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Пардон, не так понял комментарий. Тип константы на уровне языка не меняется, т.е. `1.` это в любом случае `double`. Но вот когда это значение попадает в закрома FPU, то его тип приводится к `long double` в соответствии с `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`. И этот `long double` видимо и пролазит в диагностическое сообщение. В общем, имеет смысл найти другой компилятор, где `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2` и посмотреть на его ошибки. Мне кажется, что gcc тут просто выводит наружу свои вычислительные "потроха".

Answer (score 5):

Константа с плавающей запятой `1.` имеет тип `double`.

Подобные сообщения об ошибках, как данное

> invalid operands to binary % (have 'double' and 'long double'

связаны с тем, как компилятор C осуществляет преобразование операндов с плавающей запятой в выражениях. Например, компилятор может преобразовывать операнды с плавающей запятой к формату, диапазон значений которых и точность превышают соответствующие диапазон значений и точность исходного типа с плавающей запятой. Это делается для того, чтобы в процессе вычислений выражений и их составных подвыражений получать более точные результаты.

Из стандарта C (5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of ﬂoating types `<float.h>`)

> 9 Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and
>   precision), the values yielded by operators with ﬂoating operands and
>   values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of ﬂoating
>   constants **are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be
>   greater than required by the type**. The use of evaluation formats is
>   characterized by the implementation-deﬁned value of
>   FLT_EVAL_METHOD:24)
>
> -1 indeterminable; 0 evaluate all operations and constants just to the range 
>   and precision of the type;
>
> 1 evaluate operations and constants of type float and double to the
>   range and precision of the double type, evaluate long double
>   operations and constants to the range and precision of the long double
>   type;
>
> 2 evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of
>   the **long double type**.
>
> All other negative values for FLT_EVAL_METHOD characterize
>   implementation-deﬁned behavior.

Если включить заголовок , где имя `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` определено, то можно получить следующий результат

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%d\n",  FLT_EVAL_METHOD );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
2
```

Как следует из вышеприведенной цитаты из стандарта C это означает, что константы будут преобразованы к типу `long double`.

Если заголовочный файл `<float.h>` не включен, тем не менее, видимо, компилятор использует данную опцию по умолчанию для вычисления выражений с плавающей запятой.

Answer (score 2):

Решил проверить через `sizeof` http://ideone.com/r54ZSs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d %d %d", sizeof (double), sizeof (long double), sizeof 1.);
    return 0;
}
```

Получил 8 12 8. Т. е. это обычный `double`.

Судя по всему, в анализ ошибки закралась какая-то ошибка, потому что только там он получает другой тип http://ideone.com/45lztk:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    x %= 1.;         // error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'int' and 'long double')
    x %= (double)1.; // error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'int' and 'double')
    return 0;
}
```