# Является ли литерал float или double? C++

Tags: c++, преобразование-типов

Изучаю C++, наткнулся на такой пример о преобразовании типов:

```
float doSomething()
{
    return 4.0; // передача значения 4.0 (тип double) из функции, которая возвращает float
}
```

В данном примере 4.0 разве является double? В коде я обычно встречал, что там, где требуется не int, а float, ставили .0 у числа. Например 12.0. Я считал, что эта константа будет float. Но, выходит, что каждый раз 12.0 вызывала неявное преобразование типов из double во float?

Comment: `4.0f`, `4.0F`  — `float`, `4.0`  — `double`, `4.0l`, `4.0L`  — `long double`. И да, в вашем примере есть преобразование `double` -> `float`. (На практике в данном конкретном случае, думаю, все накладные расходы по преобразованию останутся на этапе компиляции) Тип литерала не зависит от того, чему он присваивается.

Answer (score 3):

1. У вещественных констант тип `double`
2. С преобразованием типа разберётся компилятор и в рантайме ничего не будет
3. В данном случае с тем же успехом можно было написать интовую `4`
4. У меня есть пример интереснее: [Какого типа `1.`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618380/178988)